# Is there a way to break a single child element out of a flexible box?

Tags: css, flexbox

The scenario: I have a `div#wrapper` element with the following css:

```
div#wrapper {
    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This wrapper contains three child `<section>` elements that, for the sake of clarity, we'll call Sections A, B, and C. So that leaves me with something like this:
[image: Standard layout of sections]

Beautiful. Here's the catch: I'm working on media queries now and need to alter this layout when < 800px. Specifically, I need to move Section B below Sections A and C and make it full width. Here's a graphic to help explain:
[image]

The question: Is it possible to break a single child element out of its flexible box and alter the layout in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flexbox specs are constantly changing, with the current recommendiation you could use a [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-container) with [row wrapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-flow), set the sections width so that only two of them fit in the wrapper, and use [order](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#order) to put section b at the end:

http://jsfiddle.net/LYnRf/ (tested with Chrome 22 on Windows)